# Duplicate Header error

Tags: apigee

Is there a way in Apigee to handle responses with Duplicate headers. I have a target endpoint that is returning two Content-Type header field and Apigee is returning a 502 to the consumer with the error

```
{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Duplicate Header \"Content-type\"",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "protocol.http.DuplicateHeader"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to handle this in Apigee and return the response with the last Content-Type header?

Answer (score 0):

No simple way....

First off, this is a bad response payload (but you probably already knew that).  I had a heck of a time duplicating the issue because Apache (which is what I use on my servers) won't even let me add a second Content-Type header, it just overwrites it.

Apigee is written in Java -- it looks like it's the java engine that's choking on the duplicate header and the pretty 502 is just the caught error. Whether you call to it as a target or as a ServiceCallout, you get the same failure.

The only way to work around this would be to build a proxy that uses node.js to do your callout.  You could, in theory, make a separate proxy that just uses node to read the response and return a clean payload, but be careful you don't accidentally call back to the same proxy and create a recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a python callout and make the HTTP call there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This sort of replies should be left as comments. I know you don't have enough reputation to do that, but it doesn't mean you can flood. Add some code/additional information/documentation links in order to make this post worthy. Good luck!